# AWS Autoscaling and Elastic load balancing

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

For my application I am using auto scaling, without using elastic load balancing, is there any performance issue for directly using Auto scaling without ELB?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Autoscaling determines, based on some measurement (CPU load is a common measurement), whether or not to increase/decrease the number of instances running.

Load balancing relates to how you distribute traffic to your instances based on domain name lookup, etc. Somewhere you must have knowledge of which IP addresses are those currently assigned to the instances that the autoscaling creates.

You can have multiple IP address entries for A records in the DNS settings and machines will be allocated in a roughly round-robin fashion from that pool. But, keeping the pool up to date  in real-time is hard.

The load balancer gives you an easy mechanism to provide a single interface/IP address to the outside world and it has knowledge of which instances it is load balancing in real time.

If you are using autoscaling, unless you are going to create a fairly complex monitoring and DNS updating system, you can reasonably assume that you must use a load balancer as well.

Comment: Thanks David ...I am not using my own monitoring system for traffic balance. I want to know why AWS ELB is there when Auto scaling also do traffic load balancing on running instances before scaling up and down of resources as creating new instance or termination of instances.

Comment: Amazon auto scaling does not perform distribution of traffic across your server instances, only ELB does that.

Comment: Thanks for your time David.. Suppose i am running an application to 3 server instance and not using ELB,but have defined parameters for aws auto scaling, then how AWS AutoScaling works, does is count my traffic after equal traffic distribution over server or only any server instance , it will scales instances. And tell me one more thing in such situation it is necessary to use AWS ELB with Auto Scaling.

Comment: Put it this way, how are you resolving the names of those 3 instances?

Answer (score 10):

Adi,
David is right.
Autoscaling allows you to scale instances (based on cloudwatch metrics, a single event, or on a recurring schedule).

Suppose you have three instances running (scaled with Autoscaling): how is traffic going to reach them? You need to implement a Load Balancing somewhere, that's why Elastic Load Balancing is so useful.

Without that, your traffic can only be directed in a poorly-engineered manner.

See Slide #5 of this presentation on slideshare, to get a sense of the architecture: http://www.slideshare.net/harishganesan/scale-new-business-peaks-with-auto-scaling

Best,

Comment: This has nicely explained the Difference between Autoscaling and Load Balancing.